# Converting Json to string in golang

Tags: json, http, go, unmarshalling

What I am trying to do is to convert the JSON response I got from a third party API  to string to be able to render it on the webpage. My attempt first was to create a struct called `money` which holds the 3 values which are being returned and then `Unmarshel` the bytes but I don't get anything displayed

Here is the struct

```
type money struct {
Base     string  `json:"base"`
Currency string  `json:"currency"`
Amount   float32 `json:"amount"`}
```

and inside the `getCurrency()` func

```
    response, err := http.Get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("The http requst failed with error %s \n", err)
} else {
    answer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    response := money{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(answer), &response)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, response)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, response.Currency)


}
```

Finally here is what i get from the json response

```
 {"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"4225.87"}}
```

Comment: Could you clarify? You get a JSON response then you parse it to a `money` struct then you want to convert to to string back? Could you send original JSON to the web page? If not try to `json.Marshal` it to string.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky yes i can send the original json to the webpage normally thorugh ` fmt.Fprintln(w, string(answer))` . What i want to do is to display a certain value, say currency, and not the whole JSON

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned from json.Unmarshal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to remove the double quotes from the 'amount' value in order to allow the parsing into float32:

```
 {"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":4225.87}}
```

See on Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4QVclgjrtyi

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type money struct {
    Base     string  `json:"base"`
    Currency string  `json:"currency"`
    Amount   float32 `json:"amount"`
}

type info struct {
    Data money
}

func main() {
    str := `{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":4225.87}}`

    var i info

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &i); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ugh: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("info: ", i)
    fmt.Println("currency: ", i.Data.Currency)
}
```

Comment: but isnt `str` hardcoded?  what if im getting the json from the api right away? How will i remove the double quotes

Comment: I have also updated my code in the question to clarify the api part

Comment: If you have to parse with double quotes, change the type of Amount to string in your struct.